# Why is CamelExchangesFailed_total metrics not increased?

Tags: apache-camel, micrometer

I have a Apache Camel application which is monitored by Prometheus. Therefore, I added Micrometer to my POM (see [Spring Boot Auto-Configuration](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/micrometer-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration)) and `MicrometerRoutePolicyFactory` to my application (see [Using Micrometer Route Policy Factory](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/micrometer-component.html#_using_micrometer_route_policy_factory)). But the metric `CamelExchangesFailed_total`  doesn't change, althought a route failed.

**Source**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public MicrometerRoutePolicyFactory micrometerRoutePolicyFactory() {
    return new MicrometerRoutePolicyFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public EndpointRouteBuilder route() {
    return new EndpointRouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("log:dead"));
        from(timer("testTimer").repeatCount(1)).throwException(new RuntimeException());
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Logs**

```
INFO 5060 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: route1 started and consuming from: timer://testTimer
INFO 5060 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
INFO 5060 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.5.0 (camel-1) started in 0.007 seconds
INFO 5060 --- [  restartedMain] test.TestApplication   : Started TestApplication in 6.626 seconds (JVM running for 7.503)
INFO 5060 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 5060 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 5060 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
INFO 5060 --- [mer://testTimer] dead                                     : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
```

**Metrics**

```
# HELP CamelExchangesFailed_total  
# TYPE CamelExchangesFailed_total counter
CamelExchangesFailed_total{application="test",camelContext="camel-1",routeId="route1",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 0.0
# HELP CamelExchangesSucceeded_total  
# TYPE CamelExchangesSucceeded_total counter
CamelExchangesSucceeded_total{application="test",camelContext="camel-1",routeId="route1",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 1.0
```

**Resaerch**

- If I remove the custom error handler, the metric `CamelExchangesFailed_total` is increased, but then the [default error handler](https://camel.apache.org/manual/error-handler.html#_defaulterrorhandler) is used, which is not desired for some reasons.

**Question**

Why is `CamelExchangesFailed_total` metrics not increased? Is there any way to count all failed routes with a custom error handler?

Comment: Because when the failure is handled by your error handler, the metric that is incremented is : "CamelExchangesFailuresHandled"

Comment: @TacheDeChoco It is avaible with version 3.7. I have to update first. Thank you. If you write an elaborate answer, I will acceppt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Camel LTS version [3.7.0](https://camel.apache.org/releases/release-3.7.0/) added a new metric `CamelExchangesFailuresHandled_total`, which is a counter of handled errors, see [CAMEL-15908](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15908):

> Similar to CAMEL-15255, there are some additional counter metrics we could add to the MicrometerRoutePolicy for:
>
> - Total exchanges processed
> - Number of failures handled
> - Number of external redeliveries

**Metrics**

```
# HELP CamelExchangesFailed_total  
# TYPE CamelExchangesFailed_total counter
CamelExchangesFailed_total{application="test",camelContext="camel-1",routeId="route1",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 0.0
# HELP CamelExchangesSucceeded_total  
# TYPE CamelExchangesSucceeded_total counter
CamelExchangesSucceeded_total{application="test",camelContext="camel-1",routeId="route1",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 1.0
# HELP CamelExchangesFailuresHandled_total  
# TYPE CamelExchangesFailuresHandled_total counter
CamelExchangesFailuresHandled_total{application="test",camelContext="camel-1",routeId="route1",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 1.0
```